# The probability that two vectors are linearly independent.

Tags: linear-algebra, probability, probability-theory, vector-spaces

Given the set $R^{n}$, what is the probability that 2 vectors drawn are linearly independent? I know the answer is almost 1 but I am not able to reason. Could someone please help me out?

Comment: This depends on how you define probabilities. If you are using Lebesgue measure, the probability is 1

Comment: can you please elaborate? Im not very comfortable with probability

Comment: What is your background in probability? Do you know what measure theory is?

Comment: No, I am reading the wiki page on it. Its just that I am using this result to understand a certain algorithm that I am studying.

Comment: For this to be a well posed question, you also need to say something about the distribution on $\mathbb{R}^n$ from which you are drawing these vectors.  It obviously cannot be uniform.  Assuming that the distribution has full support on $\mathbb{R}^n$ and is atomless will suffice to ensure that the probability of linear independence is 1.

Comment: @exk, Given that the poster (Bambi) has no background in measure theory, it is perhaps not "obvious" that you cannot choose uniformly from $\mathbb{R}^n$... though of course I agree with your point. @ Bambi, the important point here is that without specifying how you're choosing your vectors, your question is not well defined...

Comment: How *sure (close to almost)* would you need to be? Can this question be solved by simulations? If you're looking for an *a priori* proof then it may be that not be that any mathematical answer will be able to assuage your anxiety. This may be more a question of worldview than math.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Some intuitive thoughts:

1. The probability of choosing the zero vector is zero.
2. Aside from the zero vector, it doesn't matter what vector you choose as the first one; there's loads of symmetry. So you can safely assume that the first vector is $(1,0)$.
3. Now the probability that the second vector is linearly *dependent* on the first is the probability that its second coordinate is $0$, which happens with probability zero.

Answer (score 5):

The probability is 1, for the following reason. Once you have a vector, the second vector will be linearly dependent if it lies on the line spanned by the first vector, i.e. if it is a scalar multiple of the first vector. If $n>1$, this line is negligible with respect to the whole of $\mathbb R^n$ (negligible in a way measure theory can make precise). This means that the probability of the two vectors to be linearly dependent is 0. Therefore, the probability that the two vectors are linearly *independent* is 1.