# What is the probability of choosing $n$ linearly independent vectors in $\mathbb{R}$ over $\mathbb{Q}$?

Tags: linear-algebra, probability, functional-analysis, measure-theory

I recently made a [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4512090/on-the-lebesgue-measure-a-basis-of-mathbbr-over-mathbbq) regarding the measure of a linearly independent set of vectors in $\mathbb{R}$ over $\mathbb{Q}$. As answered, such types of sets have measure zero. That question was made in the hope of knowing how frequently one would choose a linearly independent set of vectors. On the other hand, the answer I got does not seem to be reasonable, since finding a linearly independent set of vectors frequently occurs, when made randomly in finite-dimensional spaces, like that question [answered here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/474628/the-probability-that-two-vectors-are-linearly-independent) and [the other one here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/132743/probability-of-having-linearly-independent-sparse-vectors-over-finite-fields). Now, in order to the question make more sense,

> What is the probability of choosing $n$ linearly independent vectors in $\mathbb{R}$ over $\mathbb{Q}$? Or over other infinite dimensional space?

Comment: You ask about "probability".  To answer that, first tell us **what probability distribution** to use.  (There is no assumed probability distribution on $\mathbb R$, so you need to specify one.)  You may also specify whether the $n$ vectors are to be  independent.

Comment: Your second sentence is not an accurate summary of the other question, which talks about actual bases of $\Bbb R$ over $\Bbb Q$, not just linearly independent sets (nor is the other question answering a question about probability).

Comment: Uniform continuous distribution, I think.

Comment: Your initial link goes to a question asked by "Ben Passer", not R. W. Prado.  Did you link to the wrong question?

Comment: Wow! I didn't know that duplicate questions are redirected to the other one whose such question is similar/duplicate.

Comment: Logged in my account, the question I first linked is that one I made.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Claim.** Let $\mathbb{P}$ be any probability distribution that is absolutely continuous w.r.t. Lebesgue measure (less fancily: "has a pdf").  Let $\{X_j\}_{j=1}^J$ be any sequence of iid draws from $\mathbb{P}$.  Then $\{X_j\}_j$ is linearly independent a.s.
*Proof by induction:*

If $J=1$, the claim is obvious.  Otherwise, suppose $\{X_j\}_{j=1}^{J-1}$ is linearly independent a.s. and condition on that event.

Since $\mathbb{Q}$ is countable, so is $\mathbb{Q}^{J-1}$.  The latter is isomorphic (as a $\mathbb{Q}$-vector space) to and thus in bijection with $\operatorname{span}_\mathbb{Q}{\{X_j\}_{j=1}^{J-1}}$.  But any countable set has Lebesgue measure $0$, so that the latter span has $\mathbb{P}$-measure $0$ as well.  In particular, $X_J\notin\operatorname{span}_\mathbb{Q}{\{X_j\}_{j=1}^{J-1}}$ a.s. too.  **QED.**

I do not know the answer in the case of an infinite-dimensional (topological) vector space of equal cardinality to the subspace.

Comment: Apologies, I managed not to see that somehow

Comment: Really intuitive. =)

Answer (score 2):

If you restrict your choices to, say, the unit interval, and use the uniform distribution to choose $n$ real numbers then they will be independent over $\mathbb{Q}$ with probability $1$.

[This assertion needs a proof that I can't see immediately. Showing that any two particular irrational numbers are rationally independent is subtle, but the probability argument ought to be straightforward. My original answer below is to a slightly different question.]

The same is true for a set of $n$ vectors in $\mathbb{R}^n$
If you restrict your choices to, say, the unit sphere or the unit ball, and use the uniform distribution to choose  vectors in ℝ then they will be independent with probability 1.

One way to see that is to see that the set where the determinant is $0$ has $0$ volume.

The same argument will work for any nice enough  set on which you can define a reasonable distribution. You can't use the (nonexistent) uniform distribution on the whole space.

Comment: I would like some references regarding your answer. For me, a novice in probability theory, It seems hard to grasp all such details. Where such results come from?

Comment: @R.W.Prado See my edit. Sorry not to be more useful right now. Perhaps I will edit my answer later, or someone else will offer one.

Comment: The proof is by induction on $n.$ After selecting $n-1$ independent, only countably many choices for $X_n!$ so the countably many have measure $0.$